# Find xpath with on webpage selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

**I am having trouble locking down an xpath on a website.**

Normally I would just use wait for the path to be clickable and then use it like so:

```
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, ('//input[@value="2~Replace@emailhere.com"]'))))
```

However the email `Replace@emailhere.com` changes every time based on what we specify. So I am going to have that in a variable like so: `namevar = "Replace@emailhere.com"`

But the `2-` in front of the email is the row that the email appears on the wesbite. I want to try and find the input button on the website based on the email address alone since the row maybe different.

**If I try this, it fails:**

```
###Code above this###
testvar = "*-Replace@emailhere.com"
im_blacklistaddbutton = browser_options.browser.find_element_by_xpath(('//input[@value="'+testvar+'"]'))
    im_blacklistaddbutton.send_keys(Keys.SPACE)
```

**I get this failure:**

```
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@value="*-Replace@emailhere.com"]"}
```

**Here is what the element structure is like:**

```
<input type="checkbox" value="2~Replace@emailhere.com" name="uxLvwList_lstChk_0">
```

Here is a picture of what the webpage and element looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Structure the predicate in your XPath expression to use the contains() function instead of an equality condition:

```
//input[contains(@value, '-Replace@emailhere.com')]
```